# piwik send email doesn't work？

Tags: php, email, matomo

my application use piwik for statistics.  when I config the mail section. something wrong happen.  the config is like this:

```
[mail]
transport = "smtp"
port = "587"
host = "smtp.qq.com"
type = "Login"
username = "username@qq.com"
password = "*********"
encryption = "tls"
```

and when transfer a mail  the error information is like this:

> An error occurred while sending 'PDF Email Report -
>   1.2016-11-15.2.zh-cn.pdf' to *******@qq.com. Error was 'mail from address must be same as authorization user'

and I google with this info , but nothing I found work fine.
I guess there was somewhere I can put the `address from` as I do before. But I don't find the place.

Could someone tell something about this question, thanks a lot.

Comment: what happens if you change smtp to mail?

Answer (score 0):

I have handle this question. The solution is add a line in config/config.ini.php [General] code section.

```
noreply_email_address = username@qq.com
```

I don't know how it work.  but obviously, it work.

Hope this solution can help someone !

Comment: We have created a FAQ to help about this issue: https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_34856/